# Nagios SMS notification error on nagios.log

Tags: linux, curl, notifications, sms, nagios

```
[1439979541] HOST NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;hplj2605dn;DOWN;notify-host-by-email;CRITICAL - Host Unreachable (192.168.1.30)

[1439979541] wproc: NOTIFY job 6 from worker Core Worker 21699 is a non-check helper but exited with return code 1

[1439979541] wproc:   command: /usr/bin/sudo curl --request POST 'http://gateway.smstrade.de/?       key=********&to=***********&route=****&from=*****' --data-urlencode     "message=CRITICAL-Host Unreachable (192.168.122.132)"
```

> [1439979541] wproc:   host=hplj2605dn; service=(none);
>   contact=nagiosadmin [1439979541] wproc:   early_timeout=0;
>   exited_ok=1; wait_status=256; error_code=0;

[1439979541] wproc:   stderr line 01: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `requiretty` is enabled in your `/etc/sudoers` configuration by default.  Meaning you cannot run your `curl` command via `sudo` because `nagios` doesn't have a terminal (pseudo-tty).

You can modify `/etc/sudoers` (by, for example, using the `visudo` command), search for a line that looks something like:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

And disable `requiretty` globally by changing it to:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Or if you prefer, you can disable `requiretty` for just your `nagios` (or whichever) user:

```
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
```